# Issue in Fetching the Many to One Associations in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I have designed an REST webservice using Spring Boot+JPA. I have two Entity Classes - Event ,Address,EventMember. They are defined like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Timestamp event_date;
    private boolean is_deleted;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address")
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonInclude
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event")
    private Set<EventMember> eventMember;
```

**Address :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String short_code;
private String address1;
private String address2;
private String landmark;
private String zipcode;
private boolean is_deleted;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="address",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Event> event;
```

When I am Fetching the Event By using the Event Id(Primary Key) in the JSON response I am getting the corresponding members in the EventMember entity, but the Address records are not getting fetched.
Can anyone Please let me know how can I get the Address Entities also while fetching the Event Member.

**Code for Fetching Address by Id**

```
public Address getAddressById(Long id) {
            return em.find(Address.class, id);
        }
```

Comment: You have distinct steps here ... retrieval of data via JPA ... and serialisation by JSON. Define WHERE the problem is ... in the retrieval ? or in the serialisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is expected because you are using @JsonBackReference, this will ommit the address side from the serialization

Comment: I removed the JSONBackReference from here. It throwed StackOverflowerror. I added it in the Address Class for the Event Object. Thanks @Amer Qarabsa